# How to use ObservableCollection databinding?

Tags: c#

Hello all i am pretty new to c# mvvm or data binding. I saw some examples using 
`ObservableCollection` As explanined, An ObservableCollection is a dynamic collection of objects of a given type. Objects can be added, removed or be updated with an automatic notification of actions.

I have the following code: a property of type `ObservableCollection<StudentViewModel>` but it also implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. So why it needs to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface with type `ObservableCollection` here ? why not just automatic notification?

```
public ObservableCollection<StudentViewModel> TheStudents
    {
        get
        {
            return _theStudents;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_theStudents == value)
                return;

            if (_theStudents != null)
            {
                foreach (var StudentViewModel in _theStudents)
                {
                    DisconnectStudentViewModel(StudentViewModel);
                }
            }

            _theStudents = value;

            if (_theStudents != null)
            {
                foreach (var StudentViewModel in _theStudents)
                {
                    ConnectStudentViewModel(StudentViewModel);
                }
            }

            OnPropertyChanged("TheStudents");
        }
    }
```

more background: simply to say when click button, the following function `GetStudentsAction()` will trigger------>`TheStudents = sth` in turn should told the **VIEW** that property has changed.

```
public void GetStudentsAction()
    {
        TheStudents = GetStudentsDelegate();

        IsSaveStudentsActionEnabled = true;
        IsAddStudentsActionEnabled = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ObservableCollection` class sends notifications when the *contents* of the collection change, such as adding or removing an item. These are special "this collection has changed" events that WPF can listen for (as defined in `INotifyCollectionChanged`).

It does not send notifications when you swap out the collection itself for a new instance of the collection. That's the responsibility of the object that has the collection as a property. This is the same event you have to send whenever any property on your view model has changed (as defined in `INotifyPropertyChanged`).

As a rule of thumb, it's rarely a good idea to have collection properties that can be set externally, the way you're using them. Typically you would give your collection property a private setter, and only allow external classes to add, remove, and clear the items from it. That eliminates the need to have a notification if your collection changes: you instantiate it once, in the constructor, and it never changes after that.

(That advice may or may not apply to your situation, but typically when I see collection types with public setters, it indicates a flaw in the design.)